# Remove a list of manually marked packages skipping those on which a package outside of this list depends

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I've a file called `installs.txt` which is a list of package names one-per-line. I would like to remove as many of those packages as possible without removing any package that's not mentioned in that file.

If I do,

```
apt remove `cat installs.txt`
```

APT tells me that a bunch of other packages will be removed as well since they depend on some of the packages requested for removal.

`apt autoremove` **will not** work since all the packages in `installs.txt` are manually installed.

Comment: Test removals (or dependencies) one-at-a-time instead of trying to remove the entire list at once. If your list contains packages `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`, then `apt remove foo --simulate`, then `apt remove bar --simulate`, then `apt remove baz --simulate`

Comment: @user535733 If `foo` depends on `bar`, `apt remove bar --simulate` will tell me that `foo` will also be removed. I'll then have to check whether `foo` is in the list. What I want is an argument to `apt` such that if I do `apt remove {arg} packages...`, `apt` will only execute if it doesn't need to do anything to packages not in the listed packages.

Comment: Correct. This seems like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). We don't know what problem you are trying to solve for which a list of packages seems a great solution. Unless the list is quite short, it's not a great solution. Apt is not designed for that kind of use, so your cleverness is rewarded by doing the clerical work yourself.